# How to prevent provisioning of expensive services

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have an Azure subscription and there are a number of services available.

If I configure VM, web apps, application. etc.,
there are few high-end resources which are very expensive.
In order to avoid unwanted billing,
I want to create a policy that allows only a few services and lower configuration resources.

Is there an Azure policy that can do that?

Answer (score 2):

> If I configure VM, web apps, application.. etc there are few high-end
>   resources which prices are high. In order to avoid unwanted billing, I
>   want to create policy there allow only a few services and lower
>   configuration resources

Do take a look at [`Azure Policy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview). In short, Azure Policies enables Cloud Governance and by defining proper policies, you can restrict creation of certain kinds of resources, disallow certain SKUs for resources and more.

However, as a good practice, you should have only few people in your organization who have the capability to provision resources and there should be a formal procedure for provisioning resources. One of my friend burned $180,000 in Azure in just 3 months because every developer in his team has the capability to create resources in the company's Azure Subscription. The developers in the team created resources as they pleased without thinking about pricing implication.

Comment: Ouch! You can also set simple cost alerts on a subscription as a first port of call.